# Como consigo saber si los parámetros de una funcion a la que llamo cambian en Unity

Tags: c#, unity, unity2d

Bueno mi problema es el siguiente, estoy haciendo un videojuego rítmico en Unity, versión 2020.1.10f1 y estoy con la parte en la que hago que aparezcan y desaparezcan unas notas(gameObjects) en función de en que momento de la canción se encuentra el jugador.

Antes de proceder a poner el código quiero decir que soy relativamente novato en Unity, C# y programando en general.

Procediendo ya con el código, lo que he hecho es lo siguiente: Tenemos dos scripts uno llamado "LevelManager" y otros scripts que los los niveles como tal:

```
AudioSource MusicPlayer;
public GameObject NotePrefab;
public float timeOfLife;
public GameObject newNote;

private void Start() {
    MusicPlayer=this.gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    newNote=Instantiate(NotePrefab);
    newNote.SetActive(false);

}


public void spawnNote(Vector2 notePosition, double timeOfSpawn){
    if(MusicPlayer.time>=timeOfSpawn){
        // instantiateNote(NotePrefab);
        newNote.SetActive(true);
        newNote.transform.position=notePosition;
        timeOfLife-=Time.deltaTime;
        if(timeOfLife<=0){
            newNote.SetActive(false);
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

Tenemos el start() que inicializa la variable de Audio Source, instancia una nota y la desactiva.

Más abajo tenemos una función que he hecho para hacer los niveles facilmente. En esta tomo como parámetros: La posición donde se va a poner la nota y el momento de la canción(en segundos) de cuando se crea.
Esta función lo que hace es comprobar si la canción va por el segundo en el que se supone que la nota se tiene que crear y cuando llega; la crea y le pone su posición. Para finalizar(y esta es la parte en la que no se como hacerlo) el tiempo de vida que le pongo desde el inspector se empieza a restar y cuando llega a cero se desactiva. Esto último trae el problema de que cuando vuelvo a llamar a la función, obviamente el "timeOfLife" está a cero o menos y si lo reseteo sin más obviamente la nota nunca se desactivará.

Por otro lado aquí está el como he hecho el nivel de prueba en el que solo llamo a tres notas(obviamente de prueba):

```
private void Update() {
    
    Notes.spawnNote(new Vector2(0, 0), 2);
    Notes.spawnNote(new Vector2(3, -3), 4);
    Notes.spawnNote(new Vector2(1, 2), 6);
    
    
}
```

Finalmente he pensado en que si intento saber cuando los parámetros cambian puedo hacer que mientras no sean diferentes la nota se mantenga desactivada tras haber pasado su tiempo de vida y cuando cambien, se vuelva a activar. Doy gracias de antemano a quien sepa como hacer esto, o, si no se puede hacer me de una sugerencia. Llevo varios días intentando resolverlo, tengo tiempo límite y he probado a jugar con tipos de variables para intentar comprobar de diferentes formas cuando se llama a la función y a la vez, el hecho de que todo esté metido en un bucle me limita mucho más, pero tampoco se me ocurre otra forma. De nuevo, gracias de antemano y perdón por las molestias y por hacer una pregunta que quizás es obvia.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado, efectivamente me focusee en buscar una solución por el camino más dificil, intentando detectar cuando se llamaba a la función o cambiaban los parámetros (sigo dudando de que esto sea posible).

La solución era evidente aunque no la vi, las notas, esos GameObjects con los que trato son prefabs por lo que solo tenía que añadirle el comportamiento de que desapareciesen tras un tiempo, o se destruyesen y desde el script level manager tan solo tenia que generarlas o activarlas. De esta forma no entro en el bucle en el que estaba pues, el script las genera por un lado y ellas solas si no las hiteas(las notas) se destruyen.